# How to see unminified React Native JS calls in App Center crash reports?

Tags: javascript, react-native, crash-reports, visual-studio-app-center

With a React Native app built in production-mode, the JS crashes that are sent to App Center Diagnostics module look like this :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.filter')
>
> This error is located at:
> in R
> in Unknown
> in RCTView
> in f
> in S
> in T
> in Unknown
> in RCTView
> in RCTView
> in E
> in RCTView
> in x', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.filter')

(^ This is an example from a crash report for the iOS app.)

I know that App Center automatically builds sourcemaps for iOS apps, but the Javascript stack trace is still minified in all the crash reports, instead of see the full name of variables, functions and components.

May I have missed some configuration to see clearer crash reports in App Center ?